# How to display data or names on pivot table column for analysis odoo

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, pivot-table, odoo-10

I am new in odoo. I am working on customer invoices in **Accounting->Sales->Customer Invoices** and have added product field which now coming in option and trying to fetch all products names on pivot table column header from db. But i am failed.!

Here is my work:

I created Product field and it comes like this:

[image]

The original module in addons is account and file name is **account_invoice.py**. I ve inherited this module and made a new field **Product**
code:

```
class AccountInvoice1(models.Model):
    _inherit = "account.invoice"


#     partner_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string='Partner', change_default=True,
#         required=True, readonly=True, states={'draft': [('readonly', False)]},
#         track_visibility='always')

    product_id = fields.Many2one('product.product', string='Product', readonly=True, states={'draft': [('readonly', False)]}, index=True,
        help="Shows Product Detail", copy=False)
```

But when i select the Product it does not show any products name on table headings and labels **Undefine**.

[image]

I need help related to pivot how should i do in order to fetch values of product for analysis...

Comment: `account.invoice` doesn't have any `product_id`. `product_id` exists in `account.invoice.line`. You can create a new privot view for `account.invoice.line`.

Comment: ok thnx. one more thing how can i add select options list for products?

Comment: such as i ve 2 products A and B and when user select Product 2 options shd appear for selection....

Comment: I don't think, that you can. It will work like the report in `Sale -> Report -> Sale`.

Comment: but its going on for Date Order kindly see at picture

Comment: this one:

https://imgur.com/a/Pquqj

Comment: hey did u understand my question
?

Comment: Yes i understood your question but i don't know the answer.

Comment: ok no problem....

Comment: hi can u answer my that question? its related to javascript:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46783504/expand-groups-when-button-is-clicked